# Problemas ao realizar pesquisa no banco de dados (Filtragem)

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou com um problema ao realizar uma pesquisa no banco de dados.
Tenho 3 campos de pesquisa, Cidade, Bairro, e Produto, quero que o usuário possa filtrar os 3 ou então apenas Cidade/Produto ou Cidade/Bairro, no entanto funciona apenas Cidade/Produto , Cidade ou Produto. Segue o código: Tentei alterar várias vezes no entanto quando conserto um muda o outro...

```
            <?php include('conexao.php');

        $verifica = 0;

        $produtos = $_GET['produto'];
        $cidades = $_GET['cidade'];
        $bairros = $_GET['bairro'];


        if(!empty($_GET['produto']) && !empty($_GET['cidade']) && !empty($_GET['bairro'])){
          $result_search = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE nome LIKE '%$produtos%' AND cidade LIKE '%$cidades%' AND bairro LIKE '%$bairros%'";
          $resultado_search = mysqli_query($con, $result_search);
          $verifica = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_search);
        }elseif (!empty($_GET['produto'])) {
          $result_search = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE nome LIKE '%$produtos%'";
          $resultado_search = mysqli_query($con, $result_search);
          $verifica = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_search);
        }elseif (!empty($_GET['cidade'])) {
          $result_search = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE cidade LIKE '%$cidades%'";
          $resultado_search = mysqli_query($con, $result_search);
          $verifica = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_search);
        }elseif (!empty($_GET['bairro'])) {
          $result_search = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE bairro LIKE '%$bairros%'";
          $resultado_search = mysqli_query($con, $result_search);
          $verifica = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_search);
        }

        if($verifica > 0){
            while($row_search = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_search)) {
           echo ; 
        }
        }else{
           echo "Nenhum resultado encontrado.";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu pode separar cada item e adicionar o sql numa variavel, assim ficará mais fácil obter o retorno do sql, assim facilitando localizar o erro:

```
    $sql_produto = '';
    $sql_cidade = '';
    $sql_bairro = '';

    if(!empty($_GET['produto']))
    {
        $sql_produto = "and nome LIKE '%$produtos%'";
    }
        if(!empty($_GET['cidade']))
        {
            $sql_cidade = "and cidade LIKE '%$cidades%'";
        }
            if(!empty($_GET['bairro']))
            {
                $sql_bairro = "and bairro LIKE '%$bairros%'";
            }


        $result_search = "
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                produtos
            WHERE
                $sql_produto
                $sql_cidade
                $sql_bairro
        ";

        $resultado_search = mysqli_query($con, $result_search);
        $verifica = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_search);
```

Dá um `echo`na variavel `$result_search` e vê o retorno, pois, o sql está correto

Answer (score 0):

Seria interessante vc usar uma function:

function DBSelect($table, $params = null, $fields = '*'){
        $params = ($params) ? " {$params}" : null;

$query = "SELECT {$fields} FROM {$table}{$params}";
    $result=DBExecute($query);


        if(!mysqli_num_rows($result)){


    return false;
    }else 
    {
        while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $dados[] =$res;
        }
        return $dados;
    }
}